# Cocoa: How to re-read file content after file has been changed from another app using NSDocument?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsdocument

I have a document based cocoa app that opens an .md file to display the markdown content in a nice format. If I change the .md file in another app like textedit, I want to reload the views in my app.

Here's what I have working so far:

```
import Cocoa

class Document: NSDocument {

   var fileContent = "Nothing yet :("

    override init() {    
        // Add your subclass-specific initialization here.
        super.init()
    }

    override class var autosavesInPlace: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func makeWindowControllers() {
        // Returns the Storyboard that contains your Document window.
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name("Main"), bundle: nil)
        let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("Document Window Controller")) as! NSWindowController
        self.addWindowController(windowController)
    }

    override func data(ofType typeName: String) throws -> Data {
        throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: unimpErr, userInfo: nil)
    }


    override func read(from data: Data, ofType typeName: String) throws {
        fileContent = (try String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))!
    }


    // this fn is called every time textEdit changes the file content. 
    override func presentedItemDidChange() {
       // Here is the PROBLEM: 
       // HOW do I access the new file content?

    }


}
```

**Here is the problem**
`presentedItemDidChange()` is called every time textEdit makes a change. That works great. But I can't for the life of me figure out how then to access the new `file content`, so I can reassign `fileContent = newContent`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I would call for the document `readFromURL:ofType:error:` as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocument/1515144-readfromurl).